# Excel VBA Copy / Paste macro: Ignore cells with Formulas

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a tool in excel which can take two spreadsheets, and copy the content from one to another when we do an update on the sheet itself.

The tool is purely designed to be a copy / paste tool, the current code will copy and paste  values from sheet to sheet.

I have to include logic into the tool to skip cells with formulas, if the tool copies and pastes the formulas which are currently in the source sheet to the target sheet, they no longer match and throw #REF errors. Any suggestions on how to put a for loop in here or something similar to allow it to check and ignore cells with formulas?  I need it only to copy / paste cells with numbers or values.

```
Sub CopyWorkbook()
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook

wb1.Sheets("Capex").Range("H1124:AT1173").Copy
wb2.Sheets("Capex").Range("H529:AT578").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
wb1.Sheets("Capex").Range("H1275:AT1284").Copy
wb2.Sheets("Capex").Range("H580:AT589").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to skip cells containing formulas, you could use this example as a start.
The code assumes that only formulas start with an equals sign.
Edit: expanding the example with the ranges in the question.

```
Sub example()
    Dim source As Range
    Dim target As Range
    Set source = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B6")
    Set target = ActiveSheet.Range("D1:E6")
    copy_non_formulas source:=source, target:=target

    'Extended example using the ranges posted in the question
    'For the sake of formatting, I omitted the fully qualified
    'range names.
    copy_non_formulas source:=Range("H1124:AT1173"), target:=Range("H529:AT578")
    copy_non_formulas source:=Range("H1275:AT1284"), target:=Range("H580:AT589")       
End Sub


Public Sub copy_non_formulas(source As Range, target As Range)
    'Assumes that all formulas start with '=' and all non formulas do not
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim c As Range

    For i = 1 To source.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To source.Columns.Count
            Set c = source(RowIndex:=i, ColumnIndex:=j)
            If Left(c.Formula, 1) <> "=" Then
                target(RowIndex:=i, ColumnIndex:=j).Value = c.Value
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks frank, this code will do the trick, can I set multiple sources and targets considering I am working with multiple ranges?  This loop works good with one defined range but I am working with multiple ranges on this sheet

Comment: Yes, just call the procedure with any two ranges. I'll add some more example to the answer.

Comment: I had to modify the code slightly in order for it to paste special, I am getting the right behaviour except the cells on the target page show a value of 'TRUE' if the condition is met, it isn't pasting the values.  See my modification on your post, can you see any reason why it would paste the condition rather than the values in the source cells?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Just copy the values in the cells?

Comment: I'm getting the script to check the cells in the source sheet for formulas, and if the source sheet contains numbered values rather than formulas, I need it to copy those values across to the target range, its currently copying / pasting but its pasting TRUE rather than the actual numbers themselves.  It seems im missing something from within the code that tells it if the condition is true, than perform a copy / paste on the values themselves.

Comment: If you want to use paste special try this: c.Copy //newline
                Target(RowIndex:=i, ColumnIndex:=j).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Comment: It seems the copy / paste is pasting the result of the codes condition rather than the values themselves, it might be something missing in the code

Comment: Try the above modification

Answer (score 4):

Rather than loop cell by cell you can use `SpecialCells` to identify the formulae

There are two options

1. Copy only the `Constant` cells to the destination
2. Remove any `Formula` cells from the destination

If your formulae occur in a single contigious block then (1) works easily, else this will result in a number of areas needing to copied over. So (2) is preferable

Your first range can be covered as so.

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Range("H1124:AT1173")
rng1.Copy [h1275]

On Error Resume Next
[h1275].Resize(rng1.Rows.Count, rng1.Columns.Count).SpecialCells(xlFormulas) = vbNullString
On Error GoTo 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use `Paste:=xlPasteValues` for all cells? That way no formulas get copied to the target sheet.

Comment: -1 is harsh as this is technically correct, although OP may not want this. +1 for balance

Comment: Agree with @brettdj with the DV, but in my opinion, this should go to comments first.

Comment: Thanks for your input and i'm always for people giving answers.  This will copy and paste the values but it doesn't perform teh check on the source cells first, I think we have a working solution in progess with franks answer, thank you for your input though!