# Copy data range but ignore (not copy) cells with formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have a budgeting worksheet that contains multiple sheets and formulas. A user can enter his data into the ledger, and various financial scenarios are automatically calculated. The ledger contains some cells that contain formulas, and may be over-written by the user. That is fine since the worksheet is projecting month per month, and must be updated with actual entries to keep the projections accurate.

Occasionally I update/upgrade the budgeting worksheet, and want the user to be able to export his data from the old worksheet and import it to the new worksheet. I have created a macro that exports the data for certain ranges. I have also created a macro that imports the data range to the new worksheet.

However, my problem is that the macro to export also converts predetermined calculations from their original formula (=A1+B2, for example) to whatever the result is for that formula ($1,200, for example). This causes problems for future projections in other data ranges since the formula is now replaced with a static number that cannot change based upon other monthly deposits/withdrawals.

I have tried exporting the data minus any cells that contain formulas but have been unsuccessful.  I have attached my working export code (as I have many sheets and ranges, I have only posted the minimum to show what I have working). I have also attached the code I used for ignoring cells with formulas (inspired by this post [Excel VBA Copy / Paste macro: Ignore cells with Formulas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25518173/excel-vba-copy-paste-macro-ignore-cells-with-formulas)).
Any help is greatly appreciated.  As is surely obvious, I am new to VBA and know next to nothing about it!

WORKING EXPORT CODE:

```
Sub GenerateData()
Dim strFile As String
'New workbook with 3 sheets
Workbooks.Add xlWBATWorksheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "Financial Info"
Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(1)).Name = "HELOC"
Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(2)).Name = "Accelerated Mortgage"
Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(3)).Name = "Accelerated 2nd Loan"
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Financial Info").Range("G6:G8").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Financial Info").Range("G6:G8").Value
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Financial Info").Range("G11:G13").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Financial Info").Range("G11:G13").Value
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("HELOC").Range("D13:F74").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HELOC").Range("D13:F74").Value
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("HELOC").Range("D86:F147").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HELOC").Range("D86:F147").Value
End Sub
```

NON-WORKING:IGNORE CELLS WITH FORMULA

```
Sub example()
Dim source As Range
Dim target As Range
Set source = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("HELOC").Range("D13:F877")
Set target = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HELOC").Range("D13:F877")
copy_non_formulas source:=source, target:=target
copy_non_formulas source:=Range("D13:F74"), target:=Range("D13:F74")
copy_non_formulas source:=Range("D86:F147"), target:=Range("D86:F147")
End Sub

Public Sub copy_non_formulas(source As Range, target As Range)
'Assumes that all formulas start with '=' and all non formulas do not
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim c As Range
For i = 1 To source.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To source.Columns.Count
        Set c = source(RowIndex:=i, ColumnIndex:=j)
        If Left(c.Formula, 1) <> "=" Then
            target(RowIndex:=i, ColumnIndex:=j).Value = c.Value
        End If
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple subroutine which moves only constant values from `Sheet1` to a new workbook.

It should be simple to edit this to your requirements, but let me know if you have any problems.

```
Sub CopyWithoutFormulas()
    Dim newWorkbook As Workbook
    Set newWorkbook = Workbooks.Add

    Dim formulas As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set formulas = Sheet1.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If formulas Is Nothing Then
        'no formulas so move all values across in one batch
        newWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range(Sheet1.UsedRange.Address).Value = Sheet1.UsedRange.Value
    Else
        'formulas found so only move constants across
        Dim r As Range
        For Each r In Sheet1.UsedRange
            If Intersect(r, formulas) Is Nothing Then
                newWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range(r.Address).Value = r.Value
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will try when I have time and report back in a day or 2.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it seems to work just fine. How does it fail, on what data?

You are in fact copying values from a range and pasting them *to the same range*, so there is no way of knowing whether it worked. Try to update these lines, set source and target to different ranges. For example, instead

```
copy_non_formulas source:=Range("D13:F74"), target:=Range("D13:F74")
copy_non_formulas source:=Range("D86:F147"), target:=Range("D86:F147")
```

you could try

```
copy_non_formulas source:=Sheets(1).Range("D13:F74"), target:=Sheets(2).Range("D13:F74")
copy_non_formulas source:=Sheets(1).Range("D86:F147"), target:=Sheets(2).Range("D86:F147")
```

Comment: It failed maybe because I don't really know what I'm doing :)   I had tried combining the second code into the first...but after seeing it posted here, now I'm wondering if i am supposed to have each section coded individually. I will try again when I have more time and report back...maybe not for a day or 2.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried several suggestions from this site, as well others, but since I am not really sure how to write code in the first place, I am getting nowhere. For the record, the code I posted as "working" I tweaked from an online source and it does exactly what I want...except it copies cells with formulas. The "working" code creates a new workbook with the same tabs, and exports the data to the same respective cells. Now if only I can  edit my existing "working" code to eliminate the copying of cells with formulas? For reference here is the full "working" code minus all the sheets/data ranges.

```
Sub GenerateData()
Dim strFile As String
'New workbook with 3 sheets
Workbooks.Add xlWBATWorksheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "Financial Info"
Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(1)).Name = "HELOC"
Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(2)).Name = "Accelerated Mortgage"
Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(3)).Name = "Accelerated 2nd Loan"

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Financial Info").Range("G6:G8").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Financial Info").Range("G6:G8").Value
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Financial Info").Range("G11:G13").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Financial Info").Range("G11:G13").Value

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("HELOC").Range("D13:F74").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HELOC").Range("D13:F74").Value
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("HELOC").Range("D86:F147").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HELOC").Range("D86:F147").Value

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "Exported Data.xlsx"

End Sub
```